# Some simple operators in the Lambda calculus and their interpretation

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus, monads

In Phillip Wadler's ["Monads and composable continuations"](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Monads-and-Composable-Continuations-Wadler/3d2231608c7ba19935c610afd60f13bbe89d6b55) (published in Lisp and Symbolic Computation, 1994, [doi.org/10.1007/BF01019944](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01019944)) the following rules (amongst others) are listed as being part of the Lambda calculus:

1. $\hspace{0.2cm}d + e$
2. $\hspace{0.2cm} \text{if}\hspace{0.2cm} c \hspace{0.2cm} \text{then} \hspace{0.2cm} d \hspace{0.2cm} \text{else} \hspace{0.2cm} e$
3. $\hspace{0.2cm}\text{let} \hspace{0.2cm} x = d \hspace{0.2cm} \text{in} \hspace{0.2cm} e$
4. $\hspace{0.2cm}\text{letrec} \hspace{0.2cm} f = (\lambda x . d) \hspace{0.2cm} \text{in} \hspace{0.2cm}e$

However, I do not know what their precise interpretation in the Lambda calculus is. Can anyone provide me with their interpretations?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are not lambda calculus; citing [the document you linked](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d22/31608c7ba19935c610afd60f13bbe89d6b55.pdf):

> the work presented here demonstrates the utility of a functional
>   language as a ‘power tool’ for performing experiments in theoretical
>   computer science. At various points we will need to know the most
>   general type of a given form that can be assigned to a lambda
>   expression. This was easily computed using an implementation of a
>   functional language that encorporates the Hindley-Milner type
>   reconstruction algorithm [7, 1]. **The implementation used was Gofer**, a dialect of Haskell implemented by Mark Jones.

While the first 2 examples can be expressed in pure lambda calculus (e.g. using the Church encoding), it is impossible with the latter 2, as it only has anonymous functions.

Comment: Thank you :). How can the first two examples be understood in the pure lambda calculus and what is the intuitive meaning of the other two examples? Isn't the third example just the variable substitution operation, which is part of the lambda calculus?

Comment: @user65526 Wikipedia has a pretty nice page on Church [addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Calculation_with_Church_numerals) (1) and [booleans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans) (2). Examples 3 and 4 are statements while *pure* LC only recognizes expressions; there is variable substitution, but it cannot be written as a lambda term. I'm not knowledgeable about Gofer, but it seems that it is inspired by (if not based on) the typed lambda calculus and statements are a part of the language.